# Development of the symbol for the complement of the set B in A

Tags: mathematics

Complement of the set B in A is indicated as A\B (see$_1$). Is there any significance for this slanted version of the symbol? Who first introduced it?

---

Source: $_1$ Fundamental Concepts of Abstract Algebra by Gertrude Ehrlich.

Answer (score 5):

See [ISO 31-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11#Sets) part of  international standard ISO 31 (1992) that defines mathematical signs and symbols for use in physical sciences and technology :

> $A \setminus B$ : *difference* between $A$ and $B$; $A$ *minus* $B$. The set of elements which belong to $A$ but not to $B$.
>
> > $A \setminus B = \{ x ∣ x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B \}$
> >
> > $A − B$ should not be used.

Originally was $A-B$; from [Hausdorff](https://books.google.it/books?id=yvVIdH16k0YC&pg=PA14) (1927, 1937), [Kuratowski](https://books.google.it/books?id=WZLOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA2) (1933) and [Bourbaki](https://books.google.it/books?id=7eclBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA71) (1939-1957), to [Halmos](https://books.google.it/books?id=jV_aBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1960) and [Devlin](https://books.google.it/books?id=hCv-vFu4jskC&pg=PA4) (1979, 1993).

Answer (score 3):

Originally a set difference was written $A - B$.  But of course when $A,B$ are sets of numbers, that may also mean $\{a-b : a \in A , b \in B\}$.  So it is confusing.  To reduce confusion, one can see $A \sim B$ for this subtraction, or (most common nowadays) $A \setminus B$ as you note.

(I have no information on who first used it.)